# Incompatible versions of camel-activemq component and camel-http4 component

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a Spring-boot Camel application that receives HTTP requests and has to put them on an ActiveMQ.

I am using Maven to handle my dependencies, but I have a problem with the Camel-ActiveMQ component.

When using camel I am trying to keep the versions of different components the same. So far version 2.24.2 was working fine until I wanted to add a route with an ActiveMQ endpoint. There is no Camel-ActiveMQ 2.24.2 version in the Maven repositories that I am looking in.

I can not find a version of the Camel-ActiveMQ artifact that matches my other camel-components.

Some links to the components that I am using:
- [Camel-ActiveMQ](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-activemq)
- [Camel-HTTP4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-http4)
- [Camel-Spring-Boot-Starter](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-spring-boot-starter)

I have tried using mixed versions of Camel Components (e.g. 2.24.2 for all components but 3.0.0-RC1 for ActiveMQ). This causes class loading exceptions on runtime due to multiple versions of classes being available.

I have found a versions that exist for the rest of my components and Camel-ActiveMQ (3.0.0-M1) but this again gives classloading exceptions when running the applications

Where can I find compatible versions?

Answer (score 0):

Reading further I found the following in the [Camel-ActiveMQ documentation:](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/activemq-component.html)

```
SPRING BOOT AUTO-CONFIGURATION
When using Spring Boot make sure to use the following Maven dependency to have support for auto configuration:

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-activemq-starter</artifactId>
  <version>x.x.x</version>
  <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

There is no 2.24.2 version available, but running with 3.0.0-M1 seems to work. Seems that the Camel-Spring-Boot functionality is kinda new, and will force me to use a 3.x version of camel.

Comment: I am using springboot camel and using version 2.23.2 of camel. Using activemq and HTTP4 with no problems. Never ever mix Camel versions. All has to be of the same level.